# Select input not appearing in my POST method

Tags: php, html, symfony

I'm trying to add something to a database depending on the selection from a drop-down menu (select input) which looks like this:

```
<select class="custom-select" name="roles">
    <option selected disabled>Choose a role</option>
    {% for role in siteinfo.roles if role.name != 'Admin' and role.name != 'Developer' %}                                
        <option value="1">{{role.name}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

(I'm also using a twig to populate the select input.)

My PHP code (using RedBean) is as follows:

```
private function adduser($context)
    {
        $now = $context->utcnow(); # make sure time is in UTC
        $fdt = $context->formdata();
        $u = R::dispense('user');
        $u->login = $fdt->mustpost('login');
        $u->email = $fdt->mustpost('email');
        $u->active = 1;
        $u->confirm = 1;
        $u->joined = $now;
        R::store($u);
        $u->setpw($fdt->mustpost('password'));
        if ($fdt->post('admin', 0) == 1)
        {
            $u->addrole('Site', 'Admin', '', $now);
        }
        if ($fdt->post('devel', 0) == 1)
        {
            $u->addrole('Site', 'Developer', '', $now);
        }
        if ($fdt->post('roles', 0) == 1)
        {
            $u->addrole('Site', 'Student', '', $now);
        }
        echo $u->getID();
    }
```

The post() function just returns 1 if the value passed ('roles' in my case) is in the $_POST array, else it returns the second parameter, 0.

I'm just adding the role Student for any selection at this point, but even this doesn't work. I've tested all the code in an isolated environment and managed to check if it is in the $_POST array, but I cannot get it running with the rest of my code.

*Also thought it might be worth noting; I added the same functionality but used checkboxes, which worked fine. This is why I think it is purely the select input.*

Comment: Dump the `$_POST` collection using `var_dump` so you can see what's there. Also, is the `<select>` element inside a `<form>` element?

Comment: `<option name="role" value="1">` Change the value to something other than 1 if you don't want it to return 1

Comment: @miknik I want it to return 1 because I'm comparing it with 1 (post('roles', 0) == 1).

Comment: For one thing, only `<select>` bears the name attribute, not `<option>`, far as I know.

Comment: @Dai I'm not sure how to var_dump, if I add it to the bottom of my function nothing happens.